Otp is not verifying
Tech stack being used: Next js jsx, Prisma, Postgre, Zod, Nodemailer, Crypto
Issue: When I sign up and fill in the required data (Name, email, Password), an otp (one-time password) is generated and is sent to the entered email, and it is also stored in the db model called "OTP" but when I enter the otp received in the email it shows the error Invalid or expired OTP in frontend.
This is the verifyOtp.js code
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { email, otp } = req.body;
    try {
      const storedOtp = await prisma.otp.findFirst({
        where: { email, otp },
        orderBy: { createdAt: "desc" },
      });

      if (
        !storedOtp ||
        new Date() - new Date(storedOtp.createdAt) > 10 * 60 * 1000
      ) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid or expired OTP" });
      }

      const { name, password } = req.body;
      const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { email },
      });

      if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exists" });
      }

      const user = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          email,
          name,
          password,
          emailVerified: new Date(),
          role: "USER",
        },
      });

      await prisma.otp.deleteMany({ where: { email } });

      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "OTP verified successfully, user created", user });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error verifying OTP", error);
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ message: `Error verifying OTP: ${error.message}` });
    }
  }

  return res.status(405).json({ message: "Method Not Allowed" });
}

While this is the sendOtp.js code
import { prisma } from "@/lib/db";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();

    try {
      await prisma.otp.create({
        data: {
          email,
          otp,
        },
      });
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        auth: {
          user: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
          pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS,
        },
      });

      const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
        to: email,
        subject: "Your OTP Verification Code",
        text: `Your OTP Verification code is ${otp}`,
      };

      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

      return res.status(200).json({ message: "OTP sent successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending OTP:", error);
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ message: "Failed to send OTP", error: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ message: "Method Not Allowed" });
  }
}

and this is the verifyOtp.jsx
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function VerifyOtp() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    email: localStorage.getItem("userEmail"),
    otp: "",
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleOtpSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    if (!data.email) {
      setError("Email not found");
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/verifyOtp",
        data
      );
      if (response.data) {
        setIsVerified(true);
        router.push("/SignIn");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error verifying OTP: ${error.response?.data?.message}`);
      setError(`${error.response?.data?.message}`);
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-50 font-[sans-serif]">
      <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-6 px-4">
        <div className="max-w-md w-full">
          <div className="p-8 rounded-2xl bg-white shadow">
            <h2 className="text-gray-800 text-center text-2xl font-bold">
              Verify OTP
            </h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleOtpSubmit} className="mt-8 space-y-4">
              <input
                name="otp"
                type="text"
                value={data.otp}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Enter OTP"
                className="w-full py-3 px-4 text-sm tracking-wide rounded-lg border border-gray-300"
                required
              />
              {error && <p className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">{error}</p>}
              {isVerified && (
                <p className="text-green-500 text-sm mt-2">OTP Verified!</p>
              )}
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="w-full py-3 px-4 text-sm tracking-wide rounded-lg text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none"
                disabled={loading}
              >
                {loading ? "Verifying..." : "Verify OTP"}
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Also when the otp is sent, only one otp is received in the mail, while two otps are stored in two rows on postgre with the same email.
